# Avoid the deployment HDInsight samples at cluster creation

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

The script `install_hdisamples.py` is executed at HDInsight cluster creation. It creates some folders with file samples and some tables in the referenced storage.

Is it possible to avoid the deployment of such script at cluster creation? Can it be done in the ARM template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's currently possible to avoid running the script. That said, you could create a [script action](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-customize-cluster-linux/) that undoes what the script does. This is a flaky solution, and I acknowledge it's not perfect.

I am more interested in understanding the motivation for wanting to stop the script from running. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: I took this script in particular as an example, but I would like to disable the execution of some of the scripts to reduce the creation time and minimize the failure risk. I saw in the deployment logs some errors and warnings linked to the execution of the script `install_hdisamples.py` and other scripts that I haven't investigated yet. It would be also nice to disable the launching of some Hadoop services that I don't use.

Comment: We don't support that feature. If the cluster goes into Running state, errors and warnings are temporary and resolved. I'll bring up your concerns to the team. What is your target deployment time? Why do you want to disable launching some Hadoop services?

Comment: Actually, the cluster creation time goes from 25 to 30 min. Anything substantially less than this would be great. In my company we only need spark, so Oozie, Jupyter, MapReduce, Hive (Ambari maybe?) are not necessary. As I'm not aware of how such applications are deployed and how their deployment is monitored, I can only guess that not deploying them may impact on the overall creation time.

Comment: Got it. Let me bring it up with the team. Thanks for the info!